# How to convert from float3 to C++/WinRT type?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, projection, c++-winrt, winrt-component

I'm writing a custom C++/WinRT component which will be consumed from a C# application.
Inside this component I have objects that I need to expose to the caller application and these
objects have properties, in this case an Id and a Position. The Id is an integer type, and the Position is float3.

Here are the contents of the .idl and the header file:
.idl:

```
 runtimeclass MyObject
    {
        MyObject();
        Int32 Id();
        Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float3 Position();
    }
```

.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "MyObject.g.h"

namespace winrt::TestComponent::implementation 
{
    struct MyObject : MyObjectT<MyObject>
    {
        MyObject();
        int32_t Id();
        Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float3 Position();

    private:
        int _id;
        Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float3 _position;
    };
}

namespace winrt::TestComponent::factory_implementation
{ 
    struct MyObject : MyObjectrT<MyObject, implementation::MyObject>
    {
    };
}
```

It looks like that `Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float3` is not supported inside .idl files, when I try to build the project the process fails with `[msg]syntax error [context]: expecting an identifier near ":"` error at the line where the Position() is declared inside the .idl. What would be the best way to use expose float3 property of a runtime class using C++/WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float3` is the standard [WinRT projected type for C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/numerics_h/windowsnumerics-h-apis-portal). What you want to use in the idl (which is supposed to be language agnostic) is the `Windows.Foundation.Numerics.Vector3` WinRT  type and `float3` in all .h or .cpp files, something like this:

class.idl:

```
namespace RuntimeComponent1
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass Class
    {
        Class();
        Int32 MyProperty;
        Windows.Foundation.Numerics.Vector3 Position();
    }
}
```

class.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Class.g.h"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    struct Class : ClassT<Class>
    {
        Class() = default;

        int32_t MyProperty();
        void MyProperty(int32_t value);
        Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float3 Position();
    };
}

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::factory_implementation
{
    struct Class : ClassT<Class, implementation::Class>
    {
    };
}
```

class.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Class.h"
#include "Class.g.cpp"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    int32_t Class::MyProperty()
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void Class::MyProperty(int32_t /* value */)
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float3 Class::Position()
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }
}
```